# R pop up help needed

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
min_sz<-as.vector(c(unique(as.character(CF$CITY_NAME))))
min_szv <- menu(min_sz, graphics = TRUE, title="List of Cities")
```

This gives me the unique list of cities as a pop up. I want to select a city by clicking and then it should get subset from the data as a dataset. How can this be done?

Comment: You have received two answers to your question. If one of them helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example data is not reproducible, so I can not show you what to do with your data. I will use the `mtcars` dataset instead.

First, I add a column for the brand:

```
mtcars$brand <- sapply(strsplit(row.names(mtcars), " "), getElement, 1)
```

Now, I create a list of unique brands and ask the user to pick one:

```
brands <- unique(mtcars$brand)
choice <- menu(brands, graphics = TRUE, title  = "Choose a brand")
```

Choice will contain the index of the chosen element, thus the following should print the brand you picked:

```
brands[choice]
```

So the last step is to pick the rows from your data set with the desired brand:

```
mtcars_subset <- subset(mtcars, brand == brands[choice])
```

As an example, if you pick `"Toyota"`, the output will be

```
mtcars_subset
##                 mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
## Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
## Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1 97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota
```

Answer (score 0):

menu() returns the number corresponding to the selected item, or 0 if no choice was made. In your case

```
cf[min_szv,]
```

returns your selected subset.

Including Stibu's comment: if your city name in cf occurs more than once and if you want to get the subset of all occurances, you can get this with the subset() function, e.g. with five cities in a single column dataframe:

```
cf<-as.data.frame(c("Andover", "Barcelona", "Chicago", "Barcelona", "Bejing"))
min_sz<-as.vector(unique(c(as.character(cf[,1]))))
min_szv <- menu(min_sz, graphics = TRUE, title="List of Cities") 

subset(cf, cf[,1]==min_sz[min_szv])
```

Comment: This does only work, if each city name is unique such that `min_sz` is the same as `CF$CITY_NAME`.

Comment: Cities are marked as unique in the first line of Riki's question. If there were   multiple entries with identical city names just remove the unique() function in the first line to 
    min_sz<-as.vector(c(as.character(CF$CITY_NAME)))

Comment: But he wants the `unique`, because he only wants each city listed once in the menu.

Comment: right, the question is somewhat unclear. subsetting provides a more general solution